# How do I fix the "error: cannot spawn smimesign: No such file or directory" message

Tags: github

```
> git -c user.useConfigOnly=true commit --quiet --allow-empty-message --file - -S
error: cannot spawn smimesign: No such file or directory
error: gpg failed to sign the data
fatal: failed to write commit object
```

This is the message that I get when I try to commit to a repository with a comment. I am a newbie a GitHub at this moment.

Answer (score -1):

You need to download `smimesign` for signing your commits

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).